# Printing the diagonals of the matrix and showing it on the screen so that every value shows exactly where it should be

Tags: java, loops, matrix

I have written some code to play with embedded loops at two levels. I have problem with the last section of the code just before the main mehtod ends where I want to print the elments at the diagonals only. The code prints the values but not the way I want to see them. I got stuck in the number of tabs to be given so that the value is printed the way it appears on a piece of paper when we write only digonlas of a matrix.

Here is my code:

```
package com.codopedia.java7.sep2014;

/**
 *
 * @author www.codopedia.com
 */
public class TwoDArrayExp1 {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int row = 5, column = 5, k = 0;
        int my2dArray1[][] = new int[row][column];//5 rows and 5 columns
        //Initializing the array elements to zero

        for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < column; j++) {
                my2dArray1[i][j] = k;
                k++;
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < column; j++) {
                System.out.print("(" + (i + 1) + " , " + (j + 1) + ")" + " = " + " " + my2dArray1[i][j] + "\t");
            }
            System.out.println();//För att börja en ny rad
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println();

        for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < column; j++) {
                if (j > i) {//When column is greater than row (Printing on the digagonal and below it only.)
                    continue;//Stop printing at this row and go to the next row
                }
                //System.out.print("(" + (i + 1) + " , " + (j + 1) + ")" + " = " + " " + my2dArray1[i][j] + "\t");
                System.out.print(my2dArray1[i][j] + "\t");
            }
            System.out.println();//För att börja nya rad.
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println();

        for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < column; j++) {
                if (j >= i) {  //Priniting on the diagonal and above it only.                  
                    System.out.print(my2dArray1[i][j] + "\t");
                }
            }
            System.out.println();//För att börja nya rad.
            for (int x = 0; x <= i; x++) {
                System.out.print("\t");
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println();

        for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < column; j++) {
                if (i == j) {
                    System.out.print(my2dArray1[i][j]);
                }

            }
            System.out.println();//För att börja nya rad.  
            for (int x = 0; x <= i; x++) {
                System.out.print("\t");//Moving to the place where we want to print
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println();

        for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
            int tab = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < column; j++) {
                //setting the tab with each pass of the external loop
                //i.e, when we move to the next row. The while loop does the trick
                while (tab != (column - (i + 1))) {
                    System.out.print("\t");
                    tab++;
                }
                if (j == (column - (i + 1))) {
                    System.out.print(my2dArray1[i][j]);
                    System.out.println();//För att börja nya rad.  
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println();

        for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < column; j++) {

                if ((j == i) || (j == (column - (i + 1)))) {
                    System.out.print(my2dArray1[i][j]);
                    for (int tabs = 0; tabs <= (column - (i + 1)); tabs++) {
                        System.out.print("\t");
                    }
                }
            }
            System.out.println();//För att börja nya rad.  
        }
    }//method main ends here.
}//class TwoDArrayExp1 ends here.
```

[image: Here is the output with the problematic area highlighted in red color]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your considering way too many condition to achieve a simple task that makes your code look too messed up, why not print it old school manner :

```
for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
     for (int j = 0; j < column; j++) {
          if ((i == j) || (i+j+1) == row )
              System.out.print(my2dArray1[i][j]);//print content if diagonal
          else 
              System.out.print('\t');//else print only tab space
     }
     System.out.println();
}
```

or to simply put :

```
for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
     for (int j = 0; j < column; j++)
          System.out.print(((i == j) || (i+j+1) == row ) ? my2dArray1[i][j] : '\t');
     System.out.println();
}
```

**Logic :**

- Left diagonal : `i=j`
- right diagonal : `sum of (row index + column index) = total row count`

**output screen**

```
505 225 418 283 813 965 
802 747 969 309 871 265 
680 609 690 930 504 747 
117 862 860 700 901 720 
695 394 180 524 293 528 
934 154 303 401 795 923 

------------------------

505                 965 
    747         871     
        690 930         
        860 700         
    394         293     
934                 923
```

Comment: That is not the answer to my question. Your code does exactly the same things (perhaps in a better way, I agree) as my code does. Thank you for your attempt but the problem is in the last pair of embedded for loop as it does not do what I want it to do for me, i.e., print both the diagonals values in the shape of an X.

Comment: @AjmalKhan : ok...so you want both the diagonals printed??? I agree above code does only for 1!!

Comment: Yes, the last pair of embedded loops already does the trick, that is access the exact cell in the table to pick up the required value but printing is trickier for me as they do not look like X on the screen.

Comment: Please see the image that I have just added that shows the output. The last section of the pictures with red cross shows where there is problem with the formation of the output on the screen.

Comment: @AjmalKhan : for that case, jus modify `IF` condition...see updated answer!

Comment: The output of your code is:09994
96989
991299
9169189
2099924 which is not the required output. The reauired output is            0     4     
6    8    
12   
16  18  
20 24                     But display is not correct in the form of a multiplication sign kind of diagram as shown in the last section of the image above.

Comment: @AjmalKhan : may be you need to improve you programming logic...i though you struggled with pattern....so i showed that....just increment printing value by 2 everytime it prints....makes sense???

Comment: I agree with you that the problem was not in the second attempt of your solution because that was perfect. The problem was that with "\t" I could not see the output exactly as it should look. So I decided to manually check it on paper and  pencil and found out that your ligic is correct. So I just replaced the "\t" with a space " " and the pattern looks exactly as I was expecting. It was because some elements are single digits and some are double digits so their aligning was not that obvious with "\t". Your solution is correct and better with fewer lines of code. Thank you very much for help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61176/discussion-between-noobeditor-and-ajmal-khan).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the final code that prints different parts of a matrix as shown in the picture below:

[image]

Here is the code for the output given above:

```
package com.codopedia.java7.sep2014;
```

/**
 *
 * @author www.codopedia.com
 */
public class TwoDArrayExp1 {

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    int row = 15, column = 15, k = 10;
    int my2dArray1[][] = new int[row][column];//5 rows and 5 columns
    //Initializing the array elements to zero

    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < column; j++) {
            my2dArray1[i][j] = k;
            k++;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < column; j++) {
            System.out.print("(" + (i + 1) + " , " + (j + 1) + ")" + " = " + " " + my2dArray1[i][j] + "\t");
        }
        System.out.println();//För att börja en ny rad
    }
    System.out.println("\nThe elements of the matrix are:");
    System.out.println();
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < column; j++) {
            System.out.print((my2dArray1[i][j] + "\t"));
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    System.out.println("\nTranspose of the matrix is:");
    System.out.println();
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < column; j++) {
            System.out.print((my2dArray1[j][i] + "\t"));
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();

    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < column; j++) {
            if (j > i) {//When column is greater than row (Printing on the digagonal and below it only.)
                continue;//Stop printing at this row and go to the next row
            }
            //System.out.print("(" + (i + 1) + " , " + (j + 1) + ")" + " = " + " " + my2dArray1[i][j] + "\t");
            System.out.print(my2dArray1[i][j] + "\t");
        }
        System.out.println();//För att börja nya rad.
    }
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();

    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < column; j++) {
            if (j >= i) {  //Priniting on the diagonal and above it only.                  
                System.out.print(my2dArray1[i][j] + "\t");
            }
        }
        System.out.println();//För att börja nya rad.
        for (int x = 0; x <= i; x++) {
            System.out.print("\t");
        }
    }
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();

    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < column; j++) {
            System.out.print((i == j) ? my2dArray1[i][j] : "\t");
        }
        System.out.println();//För att börja nya rad.  
    }
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();

    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        int tab = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < column; j++) {
            //setting the tab with each pass of the external loop
            //i.e, when we move to the next row. The while loop does the trick
            while (tab != (column - (i + 1))) {
                System.out.print("\t");
                tab++;
            }
            if (j == (column - (i + 1))) {
                System.out.print(my2dArray1[i][j]);
                System.out.println();//För att börja nya rad.  
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < column; j++) {
            //Left diagonal : i=j
            //right diagonal : sum of (row index + column index) = total number of rows -1 (We subtract 1 becuase array starts from zero)
            System.out.print(((i == j) || (i + j) == (row - 1)) ? my2dArray1[i][j] : " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < column; j++) {
            if ((i + j) <= (row - 1)) {
                System.out.print(my2dArray1[i][j] + "\t");
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();

    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < column; j++) {
            if ((i + j) >= (row - 1)) {
                System.out.print(my2dArray1[i][j] + "\t");
            } else {
                System.out.print("\t");
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
            if (((i + j) > row - 1)) {
                continue;
            }
            System.out.print(my2dArray1[i][j] + "\t");
            if (i == j) {
                continue;
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < column; j++) {
            if (((i + j) >= row - 1)) {
                System.out.print((i <= j) ? (my2dArray1[i][j] + "\t") : "\t");
            } else {
                System.out.print("\t");
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < column; j++) {
            if (i <= j) {
                System.out.print(((i + j) > (row - 1)) ? "\t" : (my2dArray1[i][j] + "\t"));
            } else {
                System.out.print("\t");
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < column; j++) {
            if ((i + j) >= (row - 1)) {
                System.out.print((i >= j) ? (my2dArray1[i][j] + "\t") : "\t");
            } else {
                System.out.print("\t");
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < column; j++) {
            if (i == (row / 2)) {
                System.out.print(my2dArray1[i][j] + "\t");
            } else {
                System.out.print((j == (column / 2)) ? (my2dArray1[i][j] + "\t") : "\t");
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println();
    }
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();
}//method main ends here.
```

}//class TwoDArrayExp1 ends here.

Comment: Try defining methods for each diagonal your code is a mess!